# I can not write in file

Tags: java, jsp, cpanel

i use tomcat5.32 + cpanel .

my code is :

```
<%
String path = application.getRealPath("");
path +="/as.txt" ;
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(path);
fos.write("this is test ?".getBytes());
fos.flush();
fos.close();
%>
```

when requested get this error :

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/domainname/public_html/ROOT/as.txt (Permission denied)
java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:179)
java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:70)
org.apache.jsp.newjsp2_jsp._jspService(newjsp2_jsp.java:61)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:98)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:369)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:308)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:259)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
```

the perms is 0644 but my program can not write in own files .

please help me

Comment: is the owner of the ROOT dir the same as the user that runs the tomcat server?

Answer (score 1):

The error is quite clear, you **don't** have *write* permissions to the file.

Your permission, `0644` adds `Read/Write` rights only to the user **owning** the file. Either 
make your Tomcat user the owner, or include the user to the files group and apply the permission `0664`.

Comment: i apply the permission 0664.  but yet get permission Error .

Comment: @amir2, are you sure the Tomcat user is a member of the group the file belongs too?

Comment: the my host manager Said : tomcat user is member of Nobody  group .root@panther [~]# groups tomcat
tomcat : nobody ,
what is nobody group ?

Comment: @Amir2, just a name - groups can be named basically anything. Does the file also belong to group `Nobody`?

Comment: the my host manager Said : public_html is member of Nobody . please help me!

Comment: the php code write to file but when used tomcat+jsp can not write to file .

Comment: You can always set full permissions to the file, 0777, to see if that helps and go from there. You should also make sure that you don't have any SecuryManager restrictions to your java environment (typically at some path `/etc/default/tomcat `on linux).

Comment: ,how set tomcat user the owner of this file ?

Comment: @amir, given the tomcat user is called `tomcat`, try `sudo chown tomcat:tomcat yourFile`.

Comment: @amir, that is easily googlable, and if you executed my previous answer you already did.

Answer (score 0):

1) Ensure that the 'user' that is attempting to write to this file actually has permissions.  JVM writing to the disk may not use the same Permissions as the User who launched the JVM.

2) Ensure all steps of that dir path actually exist prior to attempting to write to a file.